# Base64 URL decode using Python2 vs Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, decode

I'm trying to do base64 url decoding on a hex string. However, I can't decode the string correctly using Python3.

The hex string is `614756736247395862334a735a41`, and the ASCII equivalent is "aGVsbG9Xb3JsZA". The decoded string should be `helloWorld`.

My code is

```
str_encoded = "614756736247395862334a735a41"
byte_encoded = binascii.unhexlify(str_encoded)
print(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(str(byte_encoded) + '=' * (4 - len(str(byte_encoded)))))
print(base64.urlsafe_b64decode("aGVsbG9Xb3JsZA=="))
```

If I run the above with Python2, I get the correct decoded string `helloWorld`. But if I run with Python3, the first `print` gave the wrong result.

Why is there a difference and what alternative to `binascii.unhexlify()` should I use in Python3?

Comment: What do you expect `len(str(byte_encoded))` to result in?

Comment: What is the wrong result that you get? Do you mean that you get an exception `binascii.Error: Incorrect padding`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 No, there was no error, but the decoded string was not `helloWorld`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference is that `unhexlify()` in python2 returns a `str` object, and python 3's - `bytes`, because python2 does not have such class.
When you run `str()` function on bytes object in Python 3, you get just a `repr()` for that object, so `str(byte_encoded)` in Python 3 returns `b"........"`, if you want it to run in both versions I recommend you turn `str(byte_encoded)` into just `byte_encoded` and decode `byte_encoded` variable if it is Python3, so it will be like that:

```
str_encoded = "614756736247395862334a735a41"
byte_encoded = binascii.unhexlify(str_encoded)
try:
    byte_encoded = byte_encoded.decode()
except:
    pass
print(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(byte_encoded + '=' * (4 - len(str(byte_encoded)))))
print(base64.urlsafe_b64decode("aGVsbG9Xb3JsZA=="))
```